# JQuery callback to previously defined function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still learning JQuery (and as a result a little JavaScript) but I can't seem to find out how to use a previously defined function in a callback.

Say I have:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

function ajax_start() {
                      alert("starting...");
                      }

});
</script>
```

And I wish to use this in another function e.g:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
        beforeSend: ajax_start(),
        url: "insert_part.php",
        type:"POST",
        data: "customer="+customer
  });
});
</script>
```

Would this be correct? (I assume not as it doesn't...) what is the proper way of doing a callback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Close.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    function ajax_start() {
        alert("starting...");
    }

    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: ajax_start, // <== remove the parens
        url: "insert_part.php",
        type:"POST",
        data: "customer="+customer // <== as Skilldrick pointed out,
                                   //     remove the trailing comma as well
    });
});
```

You need to do this because

- `ajax_start()` evaluates to the value *returned* by executing the function named `ajax_start`, but
- `ajax_start` evaluates to [the function itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Description).

---

#### Edit re: OP comment

> "how would I include a second function in the callback. Something like- beforesend: ajax_start,other_function (obv. not exactly like that)?"

There are a couple ways to do it. Combine them using an anonymous function:

```
$.ajax({
    // if you need the arguments passed to the callback
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        ajax_start();
        other_function();
    },
    url: "insert_part.php",
    type:"POST",
    data: "customer="+customer
});
```

Or just declare a named function that does what you want, and then use it:

```
function combined_function(xhr, settings) {
    ajax_start();
    other_function();
}

$.ajax({
    beforeSend: combined_function,
    url: "insert_part.php",
    type:"POST",
    data: "customer="+customer
});
```

Comment: the `,` at the end may cause problems in some browsers.

Comment: @Skilldrick: missed that (it's early). Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @Matt Ball with regards to the parentheses, does the same rule apply if I was to call the function in some general script, e.g ajax_start; and ajax_start(); would behave in the same way as you've mentioned?

Comment: @Matt no problem. For clarity - it's only IE where this is an issue. http://drupal.org/node/559368

Comment: @Alex The difference is between referencing and calling. In $.ajax you're saying - "use the `ajax_start` function before send". If you want to call it, you'd use parens. More like "I would like to call the `ajax_start` function now".

Comment: @Matt - yes, I'm sure you are, it was more for others :)

Comment: @Alex I gave a more detailed explanation of this in a blog post: http://skilldrick.co.uk/2010/11/a-brief-introduction-to-closures/ which you may find helpful.

Comment: @Matt Sorry that was unclear, but I've solved it anyway now :P. Thanks for the help, stackoverflow is becoming invaluable!

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the link, that looks like it explains everything, I'll get reading.

Comment: btw. you can also use a 'anonymous' function by writing: beforeSend: function() { alert("only used here, and short code") }.

Comment: @Matt Ball quick question, how would I include a second function in the callback. Something like- beforesend: ajax_start,other_function (obv. not exactly like that).

Comment: @Matt thank you so much for taking the time to help me, its really appreciated. I'm annoyed I didn't think of that, but then I wouldn't have had your excellent explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

Change the value of `beforeSend` to `ajax_start`. In other words, remove the parentheses.

With the parentheses, you're calling `ajax_start()` and setting `beforeSend` to the return value of `ajax_start()` (in this case, I believe that would be `undefined`).

Answer (score 2):

just remove the parentheses, then you are referencing the 'function'-object. The () calls the function, so you would pass the return value of ajax_start.

```
$.ajax({
        beforeSend: ajax_start,
        url: "insert_part.php",
        type:"POST",
        data: "customer="+customer,
  });
});
```